# How often is $a^b$ rational when $a,b>0$ are irrational.

Tags: real-numbers, irrational-numbers

This question was motivated by the proof of the existence of irrational numbers $a,b$ such that $a^b$ is rational. I am wondering how many such numbers there are.

Let $\mathbb I = \mathbb R_+ \setminus \mathbb Q$ ( I'm choosing positive numbers to avoid complex numbers). Now consider the following set $P= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb I \times \mathbb I \, \, | \, \, x^y \in \mathbb Q \}$. Now is it true that $\overline{P} = (\mathbb R_+ \cup \{0\})\times (\mathbb R_+ \cup \{0\})$ ?

Comment: "often"?  Subjective word.  But if $a = a$ and $b = \log_a q; q$ rational.  You get $a^b = q$  say it's fair to say it's very often.  If $a$ is not rational root of rational $q$ but instead any other irrational number, then $b = \log_a q$ will be irrational.  So for any transcendental $a$ and rational $q$ such numbers can be found. Not just trans $a$ any irrational $a$ not a root of rational $q$.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. In the question "often" is defined with regards to density.

Comment: Fixing an a, what b satisfy your condition? Fixing a b, what a satisfy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q > 0; q \in \mathbb Q$.  Let $a$ be irrational such that $a^r \ne q$ for any $r \in \mathbb Q$.  (For instance let $a$ be transcendental; or if $q = 2$ and $a = \sqrt 3$)  Then $b = \log_a q$ is irrational.

Then $a^b = a^{\log_a q} = q$.

There are a huge number of these and easy to find.

Second part.  Let $S = \{(x,\log_x q)| x \text{ transcendental}; x > 0; q \in \mathbb Q^+\} \subset P$.

Technically $S = \cup_{x\in \mathbb T}\{x\} \times \{\log_x q| q \in Q\}$

It's obvious $\{\text {positive transcendental}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R^{\ge 0}$.  (Their complement, the algebraics, are countable for one thing).  Likewise for any $x > 0; x\ne 1$ and any positive $w < z$ we can find rational $q$ so that $q$ is between $x^w$ and $x^w$ which are not equal.  So $w < \log_x q < z$. And so for any positive real $x; x \ne 1$, in particular for any positive transcendental $x$, $\{\log_x q| q \in \mathbb Q+\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R^{\ge 0}$.

So $\overline S = \overline{\cup_{x\in \mathbb T}\{x\} \times \overline{\{\log_x q| q \in Q^+\}}}=\overline{\cup_{x \in \mathbb T}\{x\} \times \mathbb R^{\ge 0}} = \mathbb R^{\ge 0} \times \mathbb R^{\ge 0}$

So $(\mathbb R^{\ge 0})^2\ = \overline{S} \subset \overline{P} \subset (\mathbb R^{\ge 0})^2$

Comment: This hints at an answer in terms of cardinality, but not so much in terms of density.

Comment: Hmm, good point.  This is informal but the a's can be any positive transcendatal irrational.  Those are dense in R+.  The b's  .... I'm pretty sure for any single $a$ then {$\log_a q$} is dense in R and I doubt it'd be hard to prove.  So {$\log_a q; q \in \mathbb Q^+; a \text{ transcendental} $} is dense.

Comment: Seems likely - so close now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch of a proof.

Let $(a,b) \in (\mathbb R_+ \cup \{0\})\times (\mathbb R_+ \cup \{0\})$. If $a^b \in \mathbb{Q}$, then let $q = a^b$. Otherwise, let $\{q_i\}$ be a rational sequence approaching $a^b$. For each rational $q_i$, let $\{a_i\}$ be an irrational sequence approaching $a$. Then $(a_i, \log_{a_i} q_i)$ is a sequence in $P$ that converges to $(a,b)$.

It is well known that both the rationals and irrationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so I don't explicitly define $q_i$ and $a_i$.

The remaining piece to be shown is that an irrational based log of a rational is irrational, which is true since an irrational to a rational power must be irrational.

Comment: Don't you mean to take $(a,b) \in \mathbb R_+ \cup \{0\} \times \mathbb R_+ \cup \{0\}$.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I was assuming what I had to prove. I'll fix it.

Comment: Is it possible to replace each $q_i$ by necessary infinite sequences ? possible, but it is not obvious. I may understand if the sequences are interlaced, but not one after the other. It's not an authoritative advice, just a question and my argument ( and behind that a matter of unicity )

Answer (score -2):

Take any open interval, map it forward by raising to a power $b\in\mathbb I$, then the image open set must contain some rational number $q/p$ with $p$ prime.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: $P$ is dense in $\mathbb R_+$

Comment: $P$ isn't a subset of $\mathbb R_+$